# Advent of Code 2021: Day 6 - problems with deque

Tags: python, python-3.x, deque

The problem I am working on today is [Advent of Code 2021 - Day 6: Lanternfish](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/6).
The main excerpts of the problem have been included below to make sure this question is self contained.

> suppose you have a lanternfish with an internal timer value of `3`:
>
> - After one day, its internal timer would become `2`.
> - After another day, its internal timer would become `1`.
> - After another day, its internal timer would become `0`.
> - After another day, its internal timer would reset to `6`, and it would create a new lanternfish with an internal timer of `8`.
> - After another day, the first lanternfish would have an internal timer of `5`, and the second lanternfish would have an internal timer
>   of `7`. A lanternfish that creates a new fish resets its timer to `6`,
>   not `7` (because `0 is included as a valid timer value). The new lanternfish starts with an internal timer of` 8` and does not start
>   counting down until the next day.
>
> Realizing what you're trying to do, the submarine automatically
> produces a list of the ages of several hundred nearby lanternfish
> (your puzzle input). For example, suppose you were given the following
> list:
>
> ```
> 3,4,3,1,2
> ```
>
> This list means that the first fish has an internal timer of `3`, the
> second fish has an internal timer of `4`, and so on until the fifth
> fish, which has an internal timer of `2`. Simulating these fish over
> several days would proceed as follows:
>
> ```
> Initial state: 3,4,3,1,2
> After  1 day:  2,3,2,0,1
> After  2 days: 1,2,1,6,0,8
> After  3 days: 0,1,0,5,6,7,8
> After  4 days: 6,0,6,4,5,6,7,8,8
> After  5 days: 5,6,5,3,4,5,6,7,7,8
> After  6 days: 4,5,4,2,3,4,5,6,6,7
> After  7 days: 3,4,3,1,2,3,4,5,5,6
> After  8 days: 2,3,2,0,1,2,3,4,4,5
> After  9 days: 1,2,1,6,0,1,2,3,3,4,8
> After 10 days: 0,1,0,5,6,0,1,2,2,3,7,8
> After 11 days: 6,0,6,4,5,6,0,1,1,2,6,7,8,8,8
> After 12 days: 5,6,5,3,4,5,6,0,0,1,5,6,7,7,7,8,8
> After 13 days: 4,5,4,2,3,4,5,6,6,0,4,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8
> After 14 days: 3,4,3,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,8
> After 15 days: 2,3,2,0,1,2,3,4,4,5,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7
> After 16 days: 1,2,1,6,0,1,2,3,3,4,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,8
> After 17 days: 0,1,0,5,6,0,1,2,2,3,0,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,7,8
> After 18 days: 6,0,6,4,5,6,0,1,1,2,6,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8
> ```
>
> Each day, a `0` becomes a 6 and adds a new `8` to the end of the list,
> while each other number decreases by 1 if it was present at the start
> of the day.
>
> In this example, after `18` days, there are a total of `26` fish.
> After 80 days, there would be a total of `5934`.

I was able to solve the problem above as follows

```
def update(lanternfish):
    new_lanternfish = list(lanternfish)
    new_fish = 0
    for i, fish in enumerate(lanternfish):
        new_lanternfish[i] = fish - 1
        if new_lanternfish[i] < 0:
            new_lanternfish[i] = LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE
            new_fish += 1
    if new_fish:
        new_lanternfish.extend([LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE + LANTERNFISH_DELAY] * new_fish)
    return new_lanternfish

lanterfish = [3,4,3,1,2]

for _ in range(18):
    lanterfish = update(lanterfish)
print(len(lanterfish))
```

**However, when I needed to increase the number of days this code was too slow to finish**

I instead opted for a more object oriented approach as seen below

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union
import collections

LANTERNFISH_DELAY = 2
LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE = 6
LANTERNFISH = LANTERNFISH_DELAY + LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE


@dataclass
class LanternFish:
    pools: list[int]
    incubation = collections.deque([0] * LANTERNFISH_DELAY, maxlen=LANTERNFISH_DELAY)
    day = 1

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.fish = sum(self.pools) + sum(self.incubation)

    def update(self, days: int = 1):
        for i in range(days):
            pool_2_update = (self.day + i - 1) % LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE
            fish_in = self.pools[pool_2_update]
            fish_out = self.incubation[0]
            self.incubation.append(fish_in)

            self.pools[pool_2_update] += fish_out
        self.day += days
        self.fish = sum(self.pools) + sum(self.incubation)


def fish_pools(lanternfish) -> list[int]:
    total_fish = [0] * LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE
    for fish in lanternfish:
        total_fish[fish] += 1
    return total_fish


def mark_pool(pools: list[int], index: int) -> list[Union[int, str]]:
    marked = f"({pools[index]})"
    new_pools: list[Union[int, str]] = list(pools)
    new_pools[index] = marked
    return new_pools


if __name__ == "__main__":

    lanternfish_data = [3, 4, 3, 1, 2]
    pools = fish_pools(lanternfish_data)
    lanternfish = LanternFish(pools)

    days = 18
    for _ in range(18):
        print(
            f"day={lanternfish.day:02d}, {mark_pool(lanternfish.pools, (lanternfish.day-1) % LANTERNFISH_SPAWN_RATE)}, incubation={lanternfish.incubation}, fish={lanternfish.fish:4d}"
        )
        lanternfish.update()
    print(lanternfish.fish)
```

**I am currently only trying to mimick the testdata**

This should result in `26` fish after `18` days and `5934` after 80 days. Instead I obtain `29` after `18` days and `15820` after `80` days.

**Any suggestions on how to debug my program?**

I attempted to debug it by printing out each day. I split the fish into an incubation period where they after X days have grown up, and is placed into the pool with the rest of the fish. Instead of keeping a list of each fish, I keep a list of the number of fish which reproduce each day.

```
day=01, ['(0)', 1, 1, 2, 1, 0], incubation=deque([0, 0], maxlen=2), fish=   5
day=02, [0, '(1)', 1, 2, 1, 0], incubation=deque([0, 0], maxlen=2), fish=   5
day=03, [0, 1, '(1)', 2, 1, 0], incubation=deque([0, 1], maxlen=2), fish=   6
day=04, [0, 1, 1, '(2)', 1, 0], incubation=deque([1, 1], maxlen=2), fish=   7
day=05, [0, 1, 1, 3, '(1)', 0], incubation=deque([1, 2], maxlen=2), fish=   9
day=06, [0, 1, 1, 3, 2, '(0)'], incubation=deque([2, 1], maxlen=2), fish=  10
day=07, ['(0)', 1, 1, 3, 2, 2], incubation=deque([1, 0], maxlen=2), fish=  10
day=08, [1, '(1)', 1, 3, 2, 2], incubation=deque([0, 0], maxlen=2), fish=  10
day=09, [1, 1, '(1)', 3, 2, 2], incubation=deque([0, 1], maxlen=2), fish=  11
day=10, [1, 1, 1, '(3)', 2, 2], incubation=deque([1, 1], maxlen=2), fish=  12
day=11, [1, 1, 1, 4, '(2)', 2], incubation=deque([1, 3], maxlen=2), fish=  15
day=12, [1, 1, 1, 4, 3, '(2)'], incubation=deque([3, 2], maxlen=2), fish=  17
day=13, ['(1)', 1, 1, 4, 3, 5], incubation=deque([2, 2], maxlen=2), fish=  19
day=14, [3, '(1)', 1, 4, 3, 5], incubation=deque([2, 1], maxlen=2), fish=  20
day=15, [3, 3, '(1)', 4, 3, 5], incubation=deque([1, 1], maxlen=2), fish=  21
day=16, [3, 3, 2, '(4)', 3, 5], incubation=deque([1, 1], maxlen=2), fish=  22
day=17, [3, 3, 2, 5, '(3)', 5], incubation=deque([1, 4], maxlen=2), fish=  26
day=18, [3, 3, 2, 5, 4, '(5)'], incubation=deque([4, 3], maxlen=2), fish=  29
```

I can see that my solution diverges on day 9, but I am unsure why. Probably I could have used a `deque` for the pool as well so I would not have to do the modulo magic, but I do not see how this solves the inherit problems with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are over complicating. If you want to use a deque, use it to keep track of how many of each age you have. Then you just need to rotate left every day and add the new fish from bin 0 to bin 6 (well bin 7 before rotating):

```
def count_fish(days, fish):
    # init counts
    bins = deque([0] * 9)
    for f in fish:
        bins[f] += 1

    # run through days
    for day in range(days):
        bins[7] += bins[0]
        bins.rotate(-1)
        
    return sum(bins)


print(f"solution1: {count_fish(80, [3,4,3,1,2])}")
# solution1: 5934
```

Comment: Great answer! Aahhh, you pop you the fish at index 7 and not -1! I considered using a deque of length 6 + 2, but my issue was that the fish breeds every 6 round and not 8, Perfect, I must have overcomplicated this. Do you have a better approach than using a deque? It was the first thing that popped into my mind to solve this =)